# Android - Overlay ImageButton by TextView on xml layout

Tags: android, layout, overlay, textview, imagebutton

I'm looking for how to overlay an ImageButton by a TextView in android xml layout. For the moment when I reduce the the TextView margin top, the TextView is going under the ImageButton. I want the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use FrameLayout with padding top for the textview instead of LinearLyout